# ruby - return an instance of current class

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I noticed if I make a subclass which inherits from `Datetime`, it's `.now` will return the subclass instance, not `Datetime` instance.

```
class MyDateTime < DateTime
end

MyDateTime.now
>#<MyDateTime: 2012-06-05T16:42:57+08:00 ((2456084j,31377s,900801494n),+28800s,2299161j)>
```

It seems magical. I can't reproduce this behavior in my own class:

```
class A
  def self.a
   return A.new
  end
end

class B < A
end

B.a
#<A:0x00000001e22358>
```

I tried to read the source code of `DateTime` but it's written in C. Is it possible to write a class method which returns an instance of the class it belongs to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with self:

```
class A
  def self.a
   return self.new
  end
end

class B < A
end

B.a
```

Comment: Note: `self` is the default receiver, and the return value of the last expression is the return value of the method, so both `self` and `return` are redundant here. The idiomatic version would look more like `def self.a; new end`

Comment: Sure thing, I just wanted to change as small as possible in the given example, to highlight the difference.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: True, but in these inheritance scenarios it's sometimes nicer to be clearer. Sometimes the idiomatic way to do things just isn't the way you want to do things.